# Problem with the information displayed by the cpuid command

Tags: caching, x86, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, cpuid

The information of the `llc` cache displayed using `cpuid command` on linux is:

```
  --- cache 3 ---
      cache type                           = unified cache (3)
      cache level                          = 0x3 (3)
      self-initializing cache level        = true
      fully associative cache              = false
      extra threads sharing this cache     = 0x1f (31)
      extra processor cores on this die    = 0xf (15)
      system coherency line size           = 0x3f (63)
      physical line partitions             = 0x0 (0)
      ways of associativity                = 0x13 (19)
      ways of associativity                = 0x6 (6)
      WBINVD/INVD behavior on lower caches = false
      inclusive to lower caches            = true
      complex cache indexing               = true
      number of sets - 1 (s)               = 24575
```

Why are there two `ways of associativity`? And it shows 20 in the `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index3/number_of_sets` file? Is 20 the association degree of LLC? What does the `ways of associativity                = 0x6 (6)` show here? How do I distinguish how many cache sets each slice has?  Thank you.

I am using a server. The version is:`Linux version 4.15.0-122-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-010) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12)) #124~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP.`

The cpu information is

```
Architecture: x86_64
 CPU operating mode: 32-bit, 64-bit
 Byte Order: Little Endian
 CPU(s): 48
 On-line CPU(s) list: 0-47
 Number of threads per core: 2
 Number of audits per seat: 12
 Socket(s): 2
 NUMA nodes: 2
 Vendor ID: GenuineIntel
 CPU series: 6
 Model: 79
 Model name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v4 @ 2.20GHz
 Step: 1
 CPU MHz: 2500.119
 CPU max MHz: 2900.0000
 CPU min MHz: 1200.0000
 BogoMIPS: 4401.87
 Virtualization: VT-x
 L1d cache: 32K
 L1i cache: 32K
 L2 cache: 256K
 L3 cache: 30720K
 NUMA node0 CPU(s): 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42 ,44,46
 NUMA node1 CPU(s): 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39,41,43 ,45,47
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using other numbers that Linux gave you:

```
size = bytes_per_line * sets * associativity
30720 KiB = 64 * 24576 * associativity
30720 KiB = 1536 KiB * associativity
30720 KiB / 1536 KiB = associativity
20 = associativity
```

Using information from https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/91767/intel-xeon-processor-e5-2650-v4-30m-cache-2-20-ghz.html and https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/broadwell_(client) ) to check; these sources indicate that each of the 12 cores has 2.5 MiB of (20-way associative) L3 cache connected by a kind of ring bus (giving a total of 30 MiB of L3 cache for a chip).

Using that as "double checked reality", I'd assume that both "ways of associativity" values that were displayed are wrong; and that the first ("ways of associativity = 19") may be displaying "associativity - 1" (similar to the way they were too lazy to add 1 to "number of sets - 1") without saying so (without saying "ways of associativity - 1 = 19"). I have no idea where the second "ways of associativity = 6" came from (the chip uses "6-way associative" for a shared TLB so maybe it displayed that in the wrong place).

Note that you have 2 chips (in 2 sockets), and all of the above is "per chip" (it'd be two separate 30 MiB groups of L3 caches).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is really useful. But I want to know how each of the 12 cores has 2.5 MiB of (20-way associative) L3 cache is obtained? Because it is 30MB in total and there are 12 cores in total. Is 30MB/12=2.5MB calculated? Does this mean that each core is connected to an LLC slice? Does this mean that there will be as many slices as there are cores?

Comment: @cyj: Generally yes, Intel CPUs have one L3 slice per core like I commented on an earlier question of yours.  It might be *possible* for a CPU to have a core disabled but not its L3 slice, but I don't know if Intel has any SKUs (model numbers) with more L3 than you'd expect per core for that microarchitecture.  (Some have had less L3 per core than 2.5M)

Comment: The Xeon E5 (v1, v2, v3, v4) have both a core and a 2.5MiB LLC slice at each location on the ring(s).  Most models have an equal number of enabled cores and LLC slices, but some have more LLC slices enabled than cores.  It looks like some models may only enable 2.0 MiB of each LLC slice (at 16-way associativity), but most enable all 2.5 MiB.  Similar issues apply with the newer Xeon Scalable Processors, but with 1.375 MiB LLC slices (11-way associative).  Many of the lower-core-count model have more LLC slices enabled than cores, e.g., Xeon Gold 5222 has 4 cores and 12 LLC slices enabled.

Answer (score 1):

`cpuid` versions 20150606 up to and including 20170122 have a bug where the number of cache ways is printed twice when decoding the `CPUID` leaf 0x4 cache information. The second time uses the value in register `EDX` which actually encodes different pieces of information (see the [manual](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cpuid)). This value is 110 in binary on your processor.

`cpuid` versions before 20200120 incorrectly showed "ways of associativity" instead of "ways of associativity - 1." Some `CPUID` information is encoded as the actual number minus one because it'd take one less bit to encode the same range of positive integers.

Starting with `cpuid` version 20200211, the author of the tool changed his mind and decided that having the tool automatically add one is better than showing raw values. So in these versions, you'll get for your processor the following output:

```
ways of associativity                = 0x14 (20)
.
.
.
number of sets (s)                   = 24576
```

You can track changes to the `cpuid` tool on the [tool's website](http://www.etallen.com/cpuid.html). Old versions have a lot of bugs, by the way.

In some cases, the `CPUID` information provided by the processor itself is incorrect. Usually when there is an inconsistency between different official sources, at least one of them is wrong. The `CPUID` information for your processor is correct.